# Herfindahl index for a firm in a given year

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
    patnum  permno  class   year    
0   1706123 10006   251 1921
1   1579247 10006   72  1922    
2   1579225 10006   137 1922    
3   1605442 10006   164 1922    
4   1699538 10006   198 1922    
5   1579325 10006   72  1923    
6   1579234 10006   74  1923    
7   1579268 10006   105 1923    
8   1665388 10006   105 1923    
9   1748147 10006   105 1923
```

```
patnum: patent unique number
permno: firm identifier
class: patent class
year: patent application year
```

I want to calculate herfindahl index for each firm in a given year.

For example firm 10006 applied for 4 patents in 4 different patent classes `(72, 137, 164, 198) in 1922`. Therefore a herfindahl index for firm 10006 should be 0.25 `((1/4)^2 + (1/4)^2 + (1/4)^2 + (1/4)^2)`. The firm herfindahl index for 1923 should be 0.44 `((1/5)^2 + (1/5)^2 + (3/5)^2)`. The higher index, the lesser a firm has diversified in patent classes.

There are two more onr thing needs to be changed:
patentnum: in the new frame patentnum needs to be counted per firm per year.

My intended data frame:

```
    patent count   permno   HHI         year    
0   1              10006    1           1921
1   4              10006    0.25        1922    
2   5              10006    0.44        1923
```

Note: I am using Python in Jupyter notebook.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.unique` and `numpy.square`:

```
import numpy as np

def hhi(series):
    _, cnt = np.unique(series, return_counts=True)
    return np.square(cnt/cnt.sum()).sum()    

new_df = df.groupby('year').agg({'patnum': 'count', 'class': hhi})
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
      class  patnum
year               
1921   1.00       1
1922   0.25       4
1923   0.44       5
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it perfectly worked. I just added firm to the group by function and got what I needed. @Chris